# ext4magic most powerful syntax?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, ext4

I am trying to recover some files on a ext4 partition. I use the `ext4magic` and I can recover some files but not all files. I have used the following syntaxes:

```
ext4magic /dev/sdc1 -r -f <some-direction>

ext4magic /dev/sdc1 -R -f <some-direction>
```

`ext4magic` has many other options (such as `-m`, `-M`, `-D`). What options is the most powerful for recovering the largest quantity of files?

**CONTEXT:**

- Recovering files deleted on Kubuntu via `SHIFT+DEL`.
- Computer shut down just after the deletion.
- Hard-disk installed on an other computer on which the automount is turned off.